# How to escape the GMT in "yyyyMMddThhmmss.000GMT"?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using `JsonConverter` attribute to set my `datetime` format but for the string 
`"yyyyMMddThhmmss.000GMT"` I get dates like `"19900321T20000.000G3T"` because of the latter M. How do I escape these characters in my format string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
 "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.000GMT'"
```

I changed `hh` to `HH` since most (sane) people use a 24-hour count.

On the [documentation Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) it is shown that aopstrophe characters like in `'string'` can be used for *literal string delimiters*. Now I also put the `T` inside this delimiter, just for clarity, even if one capital `T` has no other meaning in a DateTime format string.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quote to escape like:

```
"yyyyMMddThhmmss'.000GMT'"
```

Like:

```
string str = "19900321T20000.000GMT";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str,"yyyyMMddTHHmms'.000GMT'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Change `hh` to `HH` for 24 hours, also it appears your seconds are single digit values, so  use a single `s`.

*(I assume in your question original string you have `GMT`, not `G3T`)*

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options to use your `...GMT` part as string literal delimiter in [custom date and format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- `".000GMT"`
- `'.000GMT'`

But I suggest to use single quotes because if you use double quotes, you need to escape your quotes with `\` (because of [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)) or you can use [*verbatim string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Do the same thing with `T` middle in your string as well.

Also use `HH` specifier which is for *24-hour clock* and use `s` speficier instead of `ss` because you have `5` digit after your `T` that's why it doesn't accept `HHmmss` format.

The reason of you get `G3T` it is because `M` is has meaning of month of custom string format and that's why your `GMT` parsed as `G3T`.

```
string s = "19900321T20000.000G3T";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmms'.000G3T'",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With double quotes;

```
string s = "19900321T20000.000G3T";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd\"T\"HHmms\".000G3T\"",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```